# Chat: Wikipedia images

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat

In chat, when you post a link ending in `.gif`, the system tries to import the image. This doesn't work for Wikipedia links like [File:Linguistic_map_Southwestern_Europe.gif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Linguistic_map_Southwestern_Europe.gif).

Solution: Wikipedia links which end in `.gif` but have `File:` in the right place should have a special import method.

Comment: I doubt that there any real Wikipedia articles ending in .gif (only actual wiki pages are oneboxed).

Comment: @balpha: [Oh, yeah?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.gif)

Comment: @PopularDemand: touché :)

Comment: @balpha: Here's one that's not a redirect: [.cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.cat)

Answer (score 4):

If you want the image to be displayed, link to the image (http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4d/Linguistic_map_Southwestern_Europe.gif/800px-Linguistic_map_Southwestern_Europe.gif) and not to some page that contains the image.

Comment: ... which wouldn't be oneboxed anyway, since that's not an article page.

Comment: Error generating thumbnail